# Create a dynamic google form and send this to an email in Android app

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-forms

In my Android App I am taking some information, I want to include that information and include in a google form, and send that google form to a certain email address.
Can you please tell can I complete this task using App Script and Google Forms API, if not kindly suggest another option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't the form must be run on a web server not an email.